To what extent should homework sets be changed in a math course, semester to semester?
I've curious as to the extent that materials should be refreshed between semesters, changing the contexts and updating numbers to avoid students passing on solutions from previous semesters of the same course.
Is the burden of a few hours of instructor work to refresh an assignment wasteful, necessary or somewhere in between to avoid the academic integrity problems of assigning work whose solutions are floating around the student body from previous semesters?  I'm motivated not just to run a fair course but to to run an effective one (cheaters who get away with it haven't really learned, have they?).
For better and (in my opinion) worse, the advent of chat GPT and similar AI models ensures that pretty good solutions are already available.  Is the cat already out of the bag and there isn't a need to change the coursework semester to semester?
I should specify that I'm really referring to homeworks, which are done outside of class and with open notes and internet.  When it comes to exams, with their increased weight and lack of open notes, I think the effort to make fresh problems every semester is well justified.
Of course, the answer will vary a bit based on the content of the class.  Some math classes have "classic" problems (graph theory courses seem to have a bunch: e.g. bridges of kronenbourg), and for good reason.  My course is an introductory math course and, as such, it has the students do a good amount of computation so they gain experiences necessary to build intuition (e.g. Bayes Rule, converting between numbers in different bases, predicate logic).

One scheme I heard of: Each student gets a problem with different numbers (so he cannot merely copy someone else's paper or copy something from the web).  That has been tried in the past, but it is a nightmare for the TAs who are grading it.
But now there is a new version: Let it be graded by AI.  Let the AI do the slave work.

The nice thing is services like WebAssign will partially randomize questions student by student, but it is the same problem overall.
